# Why does sed fail with International characters and how to fix?

Tags: linux, internationalization, sed, character

`GNU sed version 4.1.5` seems to fail with International chars. Here is my input file:

```
Gras Och Stenar Trad - From Moja to Minneapolis DVD [G2007DVD] 7812 | X
<br>
Gras Och Stenar Trad - From Möja to Minneapolis DVD [G2007DVD] 7812 | Y
```

(Note the umlaut in the second line.)

And when I do

```
sed 's/.*| //' < in
```

I would expect to see only the `X` and `Y`, as I've asked to remove ALL chars up to the `'|'` and space beyond it. Instead, I get:

```
X<br>
Gras Och Stenar Trad - From M? Y
```

I know I can use tr to remove the International chars. first, but is there a way to just use sed?

Comment: This problem seems that has been solved with GNU sed (tested on version 4.2.2).

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I think the error occurs if the input encoding of the file is different from the preferred encoding of your environment.

Example: `in` is UTF-8

```
$ LANG=de_DE.UTF-8 sed 's/.*| //' < in
X
Y
$ LANG=de_DE.iso88591 sed 's/.*| //' < in
X 
Y
```

UTF-8 can safely be interpreted as ISO-8859-1, you'll get strange characters but apart from that everything is fine.

Example: `in` is ISO-8859-1

```
$ LANG=de_DE.UTF-8 sed 's/.*| //' < in
X
Gras Och Stenar Trad - From MöY
$ LANG=de_DE.iso88591 sed 's/.*| //' < in
X 
Y
```

ISO-8859-1 cannot be interpreted as UTF-8, decoding the input file fails. The strange match is probably due to the fact that sed tries to recover rather than fail completely.

The answer is based on Debian Lenny/Sid and sed 4.1.5.

Answer (score 12):

`sed` is not very well setup for non-ASCII text. However you can use (almost) the same code in `perl` and get the result you want:

```
perl -pe 's/.*\| //' x
```