# sed and special char

Tags: sed, char, special-characters

im trying the following sed command, but i have no luck with special chars:

```
echo "x#asdf" | sed "s/\([^-]\)#/\1\n/g"

x
asdf
```

but if i use some special char in test.txt

```
echo "ä#asdf" | sed "s/\([^-]\)#/\1\n/g"

ä#asdf
```

why ?

this works:

```
echo "ü#asdf" | sed "s/ü/-/g"
-#asdf
```

but this doesnt:

```
echo "ü#asdf" | sed "s/[ü]/-/g"
ü#asdf
```

Comment: Works fine here. There's nothing wrong with your sed script, must be related to your locale/file encoding.

Comment: i have the follwing locale : 'de_DE.UTF-8'

Comment: It works for me in GNU sed version 4.2.1 in en_US.UTF-8 and de_DE.UTF-8. What version of `sed` is yours?

Comment: GNU sed Version 4.1.2 - maybe my question is confusing:

Comment: echo "ä#asdf" | sed "s/\\([^-]\\)#/\1\n/g" should output the same as echo "x#asdf" | sed "s/\\([^-]\\)#/\1\n/g"

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about this, because your sed commands work ok for me (gnu sed 4.1.5), but try invoking sed this way:

```
$ LANG=de_DE.UTF-8 sed ...
```

See this post for more information: [Why does sed fail with International characters and how to fix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67410/).

If this doesn't work, it may help to upgrade to gnu sed 4.2, if you can. The NEWS file says "multibyte processing fixed" for 4.2 but does not go into further detail.