# Sed command causing asian characters to be printed to file

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, sed, terminal

This is a follow up problem to a [question I posed earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6790631/use-the-contents-of-a-file-to-replace-a-string-using-sed). Basically when I do this:

```
sed '/Q/{
s/Q//g
r /Users/ericbrotto/Desktop/question.txt
}' Commision.txt
```

everything is fine, but the new output just prints to a console.

When I do this:

```
sed '/Q/{
s/Q//g
r /Users/ericbrotto/Desktop/question.txt
}' Commision.txt > newFile
```

the output prints to file, but my new string (the one that was properly replaced in the previous output) now reads as a bunch of asian (I believe Mandarin) characters.

Any ideas?

Comment: please post the output of the cmd `locale`, as executed in a local shell, AND if your sed script is wrapped in a shell script, then put it before and after the call to sed, or at least look at those outputs to see if you can identify any differences. Good luck.

Comment: Also I think it's necessary to know more about what you have in the file question.txt -- is it just ASCII, or something else?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you have an encoding mismatch.

I wager that your shell, `Commision.txt` and `question.txt` don't all have the same encoding.  Because of that, sed is replacing part of a wide character that it doesn't recognize as wide.  All subsequent character encodings are off by half a character, and the result is Chinese.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67410/why-does-sed-fail-with-international-characters-and-how-to-fix) for discussion of a similar problem.