# Does . really match any character?

Tags: sed, ascii, non-ascii-characters

I am using a very simple sed script removing comments : `sed -e 's/--.*$//'`

It works great until non-ascii characters are present in a comment, e.g.: `-- °`.
This line does not match the regular expression and is not substituted.

Any idea how to get `.` to really match any character?

---

**Solution :**

Since `file` says it is an iso8859 text, `LANG` variable environment must be changed before calling `sed` : 
`LANG=iso8859 sed -e 's/--.*//' -`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It works for me. It's probably a character encoding problem.

This might help:

- [Why does sed fail with International characters and how to fix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67410/why-does-sed-fail-with-international-characters-and-how-to-fix)
- http://www.barregren.se/blog/how-use-sed-together-utf8

Answer (score 4):

@julio-guerra: I ran into a similar situation, trying to delete lines like the folowing (note the `Æ` character):

`--MP_/yZa.b._zhqt9OhfqzaÆC`

in a file, using

`sed 's/^--MP_.*$//g' my_file`

The file encoding indicated by the Linux `file` command was

```
    file my_file: ISO-8859 text, with very long lines
 file -b my_file: ISO-8859 text, with very long lines
file -bi my_file: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1
```

I tried your solution (clever!), with various permutations; e.g.,

`LANG=ISO-8859 sed 's/^--MP_.*$//g' my_file`

but none of those worked.  I found two workarounds:

1. The following `Perl` expression worked, i.e. deleted that line:

`perl -pe 's/^--MP_.*$//g' my_file`

[For an explanation of the `-pe` command-line switches, refer to this StackOverflow answer:

[Perl flags -pe, -pi, -p, -w, -d, -i, -t?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6302025/perl-flags-pe-pi-p-w-d-i-t)  ]

2. Alternatively, after converting the file encoding to UTF-8, the sed expression worked (the `Æ` character remained, but was now UTF8-encoded):

`iconv -f iso-8859-1 -t utf-8 my_file > my_file.utf8`

As I am working with lots (1000's) of emails with various encodings, that undergo intermediate processing (bash-scripted conversions to UTF-8 do not always work), for my purposes "solution 1" above will probably be the most robust solution.

Notes:

- sed (GNU sed) 4.4
- perl v5.26.1 built for x86_64-linux-thread-multi
- Arch Linux x86_64 system

Comment: For `iconv`, `utf8` was giving error. `utf-8` worked.

Comment: @LoMaPhZ: I believe you are correct re: `utf-8` -- thank you.  I edited my answer (`iconv -f iso-8859-1 -t utf8 ...` to `iconv -f iso-8859-1 -t utf-8...`).

Answer (score 0):

The documentation of GNU sed's `z` command mentions this effect (my emphasis):

> This command empties the content of pattern space.  It is usually
>        the same as 's/.*//', but is more efficient and works in the
>        presence of **invalid multibyte sequences** in the input stream.  POSIX
>        mandates that **such sequences are *not* matched by '.'**, so that
>        there is no portable way to clear sed's buffers in the middle of
>        the script in most multibyte locales (including UTF-8 locales).

It seems likely that you are running sed in a UTF-8 (or other multibyte) locale. You'll want to set `LC_CTYPE` (that's finer-grained than `LANG`, and won't affect translation of error messages. Valid locale names usually look like `en.iso88591` or (for the location in your profile) `fr_FR.iso88591`, not just the encoding on its own - you might be able to see the full list with `locale -a`.

Example:

```sh
LC_CTYPE=fr_FR.iso88591 sed -e 's/--.*//'
```

Alternatively, if you know that the non-comment parts of the line contain only ASCII, you could split the line at a comment marker, print the first part and discard the remainder:

```sh
sed -e 's/--/\n/' -e 'P' -e 'd'
```