# Replace first symbol of sentence with capital letter

Tags: bash, capitalization, capitalize

I need help with capitalizing the first letter of the first word in sentences from an input file `input.txt`:

> **t**his is my first sentence. **a**nd this is the second sentence. **t**hat one is the third.

I want to make the output look like this in an output file `output.txt`:

> **T**his is my first sentence. **A**nd this is the second sentence. **T**hat one is the third.

Comment: We can help you if you show what you've tried first. Hint: it probably involves using `perl` or `awk`.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take some time to read http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`bash version 4` way:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/bash

while IFS="." read -r -a line ; do
    for ((i=0; i<${#line[@]}; i++)) do
        if [[ $i > 0 ]]; then
            temp=$(echo ${line[$i]/ /})
            echo -n "${temp^}. "
        else
            echo -n "${line[$i]^}. "
        fi
    done
    echo
done < file
```

Comment: Thank you it works, but it won't work with sentences starting with ľ š č ť ž ý á í é ď etc. Any ideas?

Comment: @Tommy `bash v4` handles it. If it doesn't then your `locale` isn't set to handle this. You probably need to at least set `LC_CTYPE` to a `UTF-8` variation.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
sed -r "s/(^|\.\s+)./\U&/g" <input.txt >output.txt
```

Comment: Hello, I have found that it don't work with all UTF8 symbols. This is for Slovak system and sentences sometimes starting with ľ š č ť ž ý á í é ď etc. I ideas to solve this issue?

Comment: It should work if your locale is set correctly (see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/67575/1630171)).

Comment: Well i changed my locale to slovak utf8 and it dont work.. it replacing special characters with some robish characters. Any ideas?

Comment: I checked with german UTF-8 locale and it worked just fine. Did you adjust `LANG` and `LC_*`? Does your terminal support UTF-8?

Answer (score 0):

What about `awk` way?

```
$ awk -F"\. " '{OFS=". "}{for (i=0;i<=NF;i++) {sub(".", substr(toupper($i), 1,1) , $i)}} {print}' output.txt 
This is my first sentence. And this is the second sentence. That one is the third.
```

- `-F"\. "` sets the field delimiter to `.` (dot + space).
- `{OFS=". "}` sets the output field delimiter to `.` (dot + space).
- `'{for (i=0;i<=NF;i++) {sub(".", substr(toupper($i), 1,1) , $i)}}` loops through each field capitalizing the first word of them. As first field is `this is my first sentence`, it just capitalizes `this`.