# Sed with UTF8 input

Tags: bash, utf-8, sed

I need help with my work to school.
I have got (from stackoverflow of course) this script which capitalizing first character of string.

```
sed -r "s/(^|\.\s+)./\U&/g" <$temp_file_2
```

But output of this is in ANSI encoding or what is that. file -bi shows unknown-8bit encoding format.

Is it any change to get output in utf-8 to file ?

P.S.: This sed command is used for capitalizing firs character of line. (with support of special Slovak characters like ščťžýáíéď etc)
P.S : File have to be UTF-8 because content is inserted to mysql database.
Converting file causing loosing information.

Comment: `sed` cannot convert between character encodings; you'll need a separate program like `iconv` to convert the input file first.

Comment: But I will afterwards put file content to mysql database. File contains special characters like ď ľ š č ť ž ý á í é, which can't be inserted to mysql. I got luck only when imput file was in utf8.

Comment: I see some solution to use pear -pe and sed command but I don't know to use it

Comment: Are you trying to convert `temp_file2` *to* UTF-8, or convert it *from* UTF-8 to ASCII (losing some information in the process)?

Comment: I tried to convert it but i loosed characters. I need them all.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `sed` might have trouble dealing with non-ASCII characters, especially when the *system locale* is not UTF8.

```sh
$ bash -c "echo 'abc,ščťžýáíéď' | LANG= LC_CTYPE= sed -E --debug 's/./\U&/g'"
SED PROGRAM:
  s/./\U&/g
INPUT:   'STDIN' line 1
PATTERN: abc,\o37777777705\o37777777641\o37777777704\o37777777615\o37777777705\o37777777645\o37777777705\o37777777676\o37777777703\o37777777675\o37777777703\o37777777641\o37777777703\o37777777655\o37777777703\o37777777651\o37777777704\o37777777617
COMMAND: s/./\U&/g
MATCHED REGEX REGISTERS
  regex[0] = 0-1 'a'
PATTERN: ABC,\o37777777777\o37777777777\o37777777777\o37777777777\o37777777777\o37777777777\o37777777777\o37777777777\o37777777777\o37777777777\o37777777777\o37777777777\o37777777777\o37777777777\o37777777777\o37777777777\o37777777777\o37777777777
END-OF-CYCLE:
ABC,
```

As you can see, `sed` view each non-ASCII character as several separated bytes, so it incorrectly uppercased them. One solution is setting `LANG` and `LC_CTYPE` to a UTF8 compatible locale.

```sh
$ bash -c "echo 'abc,ščťžýáíéď' | LANG=C.UTF8 LC_CTYPE=C.UTF8 sed -E --debug 's/./\U&/g'"
SED PROGRAM:
  s/./\U&/g
INPUT:   'STDIN' line 1
PATTERN: abc,\o37777777705\o37777777641\o37777777704\o37777777615\o37777777705\o37777777645\o37777777705\o37777777676\o37777777703\o37777777675\o37777777703\o37777777641\o37777777703\o37777777655\o37777777703\o37777777651\o37777777704\o37777777617
COMMAND: s/./\U&/g
MATCHED REGEX REGISTERS
  regex[0] = 0-1 'a'
PATTERN: ABC,\o37777777705\o37777777640\o37777777704\o37777777614\o37777777705\o37777777644\o37777777705\o37777777675\o37777777703\o37777777635\o37777777703\o37777777601\o37777777703\o37777777615\o37777777703\o37777777611\o37777777704\o37777777616
END-OF-CYCLE:
ABC,ŠČŤŽÝÁÍÉĎ
```

References:

- https://superuser.com/questions/1347826/how-to-avoid-sed-changing-the-file-format
- [Why does sed fail with International characters and how to fix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67410/why-does-sed-fail-with-international-characters-and-how-to-fix)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
  cat <src> | iconv -f <srcenc> | sed .... | iconv -t <targetenc> > target
```

To see list of encodings:

```
  iconv -l
```

To see if you guessed encoding of your input file correctly check

```
cat <src> | iconv -f <srcenc>
```